# How to debug a j2me application in netbeans with breakpoint?

Tags: java-me

I am unable to check the flow of execution of my j2me application using breakpoint.
I am using Netbeans IDE.Googling it I came to know that after setting a breakpoint,I need to run the app and then when the AMS reaches the breakpoint,if I go on pressing F6,i'll get to know the flow of execution .But it doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Are you talking about getting your IDE to show the call stack?
The keyboard shortcut for that would be Alt+Shift+3

Answer (score 0):

If the IDE is not doing what you want, maybe try to add this code right before your breakpoint:

```
try
{
     throw new RuntimeException();
} 
catch(RuntimeException rex)
{
     rex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nice. It's like, "what the hell happened? I saw a stack trace!" LOL